# Problem about virtual function and shared_ptr vector

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have a problem with virtual function and shared_ptr vector.
The problem is I want to use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>>` heroes vector as a parameter in my `moveForward` and `moveBackward` function.
But it has to take a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>> Units` vector as a parameter,
because monster and hero classes' child classes will use this function
but when I take a hero vector it gives this error:

`Non-const lvalue reference to type 'vector<shared_ptr<Unit>>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'vector<shared_ptr<Hero>>'`

```
class Unit{
public:
    virtual void moveForward(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>>& vector){}
    virtual void moveBackward(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>>& vector){}
};


class Hero : public Unit{
public:
    virtual void moveForward(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>>& vector) override {}
    virtual void moveBackward(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>>& vector) override {}

};

class Monster : public Unit{
};

class Crusader : public Hero{
public:
    void moveForward(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>>& vector) final{
        mv1.moveForward(vector, position);
    }
    void moveBackward(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>>& vector) final{
        mv1.moveBackward(vector, position);
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>> Units;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Hero>> heroes;

    auto b= std::make_shared<Crusader>(1);
    Units.emplace_back(b);

    Units[0]->moveForward(heroes);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you want `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>> heroes;`

Comment: @emaditaj [I don't believe you can](https://godbolt.org/z/UzjW4y)

Comment: A `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Hero>>` cannot safely be bound to a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>>&`. Even assuming that the `std::shared_ptr`s are laid out exactly the same, the conceptual issue is that you could try adding a `std::shared_ptr<Monster>` or whatever to `heroes` through the reference. Perhaps you need to throw some templates around, or maybe some kind of iterator can help.